# Can one label vertices with attributes instead of integers?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently working on formalizing a graph for my master's thesis.
This isn't a question regarding the implementation of a graph, as I am already done with that part. My graph is an undirected tree where each vertex is unique and consists of a set of attributes. For example, v contains the attributes (Id = 123, Name = Johnny, Weight = 70, etc).

I've tried to find research articles or journals regarding graph labelling vertices with a set of attributes instead of integers, but I cannot find any.

Does anyone know anything about this? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You can label the vertices however you choose; this is common in computer programs. Perhaps I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ you have a map $\,f:V\to A\,$ from vertices to attributes. This is okay.

Comment: Consider that by enumerating the $n$ attributes, labelling the graph with numbers $1,...,n$ is the same as labelling it with attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the great answers. I'll define a function to map vertices to attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can label the vertices with whatever you like. All you need is a labeling function $f:V \to L$, where $V$ is your set of vertices and $L$ is your set of labels.

In fact, graph theorists frequently label vertices with things other than numbers: [colors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)!